# Configuring parallel_tests for use inside docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I am trying to set up [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) on my Rails project which runs, in develop and test, inside a docker container.

When I run the tests `rake parallel:spec` it seems to be running each group sequentially, instead of, well, in parallel...

[image: running with 4 cpus]

Which is making it run slower than with a single cpu...

Any hints as to what might be the culprit here?

ps: Rails 5.2, rspec 3.8 and this is how my docker preferences are set:

[image]

Comment: Hi @donato-azevedo, what did you end up doing ?

Comment: Same question here...